# Core Data and Relationships

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have two objects, a `Trip` and a `Place`. A `Trip` represents a journey from one `Place` to another `Place`, ie. a `Trip` needs a `fromPlace` and a `toPlace`. So, this is a 1-to-2 relationship, but I need to know which is the "from" and which is the "to". I am not sure how to model this in Core Data. I have created two entities (`Trip, Place`), and now I want to setup the relationship(s) so I have a `fromPlace` and a `toPlace`. Do I need to add an extra field on the Place entity called `isFrom`, or similar?

If this was in a database, I would just have a id column on the `Place` table, and then two columns in the `Trip` table - `fromPlaceId` and `toPlaceId`. How do I achieve something similar in Core Data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to add an extra field on the Place entity called isFrom, or similar?

Yes. It's better for you not to think of Core Data as a wrapper around a database; the database intuition sometimes gets in the way.
Don't first think in terms of database and then try to translate it into Core Data. While you're learning how to use Core Data, just think of it as a system of objects which can be saved into a file and persist between two launches of the app.

Then, from the point of view of object-oriented programming, you have a class `Trip` which has two instance variables `fromPlace` and `toPlace` of class `Place`.

You want to make it persist on a file. So you create an entity `Trip` which has two relations `fromPlace` and `toPlace`, both of which is of entity `Place`. That's it!

In more detail, `fromPlace` and `toPlace` in `Trip` are both to-one relationships. In `Place`, you make two to-many relationships, say `tripsStartingHere` and `tripsEndingHere`. Then you set `tripsStartingHere` as the inverse of `fromPlace`, and `tripsEndingHere` as the inverse of `toPlace`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you've confused me a little with that last part :) Should I have one relationship between Trip and Place which is a 1-to-2 relationship, and an isFrom field on the Place entity? From your last sentence it sounds like I should have two relationships going to Place, but then I can't set the inverse?

Comment: I ended up putting an isFrom field on the Place entity.